# Update animated container in a listView.builder

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

How to update animated container with longPress which lies under the listview builder

```
widget.meetingdetails.forEach((tasks) {
  if (tasks['task'] == 'Meeting') {
    _meetinglist.add(GestureDetector(
      onLongPress: () {
        setState(() {
          heightChange = heightChange == 130 ? 150 : 130;

        });
      },
      child: AnimatedContainer(
        duration: new Duration(milliseconds: 500),
        height: heightChange,
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30, vertical: 10),)).......
```

above code is the way i make the list and below code is how i implement it on the listView.builder

```
return ListView.builder(
  itemCount: _meetinglist.length,
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => _meetinglist[index],
  padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 60), physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),

);
```

**Here when i longPress on the container all the items in the list updates. I need only the pressed container to update**

[image: The container before longpress]
[image: Container after longpress]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your height variable is part of this state which is being shared across all the widgets in the _meetingList variable. Thats why all of them are updated. Try extracting the `GestureDetector` widget into its own Stateful widget and handle the heights individually in the respective widget.

A live dartpad is available [here](https://dartpad.dev/ff5f25d3b79fd6e09ca4be335db031ad).

**example**

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<MeetingCard> _meetingCards = [
          MeetingCard(title: 'standup meeitng'),
          MeetingCard(title: 'weekely meeting'),          
          MeetingCard(title: 'Status Meeting'),
          MeetingCard(title: 'Another meeting'),

  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Adjustable height card.',
      home: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: _meetingCards.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index){
          return _meetingCards[index];
        }
      ),
    );
  }
}

// Define a custom Form widget.
class MeetingCard extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;

  MeetingCard({this.title});
  @override
  _MeetingCardState createState() => _MeetingCardState();
}

// Define a corresponding State class.
class _MeetingCardState extends State<MeetingCard> {

  // this height is specific to this widget.
  double height = 130;

  @override
  Widget build(context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onLongPress: (){
        setState((){
          height = height == 130 ? 150 : 130;
        });
      },
      child: AnimatedContainer(
        duration: new Duration(milliseconds: 500),
        height: height,
        child: Card(child: Center(child: Text(widget.title),),),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: i am fetching data from here. so while i refactor the code i am getting error        `widget.meetingdetails.forEach((tasks) {
  if (tasks['task'] == 'Meeting') {
    _meetinglist.add(........).......`

Comment: Sorry I couldn't understand you comment. Where are you fetching and what error are you getting..? In your code you will have to use, `_meetingList.add(MeetingCard())` along with other information relevant to the MeetingCard.

Comment: I am using a stateful widget in which i implement listView Builder

Comment: Your meetingcard should be a statefulwidget with height defined in it as shown in the answer.  It's parent widget cannot hold state of height for all it's children widget in this case your meetingcard widget.. check the dartpad I shared..

Comment: Hi @AsbahRiyas, did it work..? Hope you are not stuck.. :-)